# Play Billing: Change between plans with free trials of different duration

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

In an Android app I offer a subscription with base plans of different billing periods, say monthly and yearly. I offer a free trial of 1 week for the monthly plan, and a free trial of 2 weeks for the yearly plan. I allow users to switch between the billing periods.

Now if a user is in the free trial of the monthly plan and switches to the yearly plan, will the free trial be extended to 2 weeks? Also, what will happen in the reverse case?

This is not explained here https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions or here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12154973, and cannot be tested since for test subscriptions all free trials are 3 minutes: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test#renewals.

Comment: Best guess: Ask Google.

Comment: will do so if not someone here happens to have experience with this